# Is there an easy way to set the style for a Label to use the same style as the FormLayout in Vaadin 14 and higher?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin22

Specifically if I have:

```
FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
formLayout.add(new TextField("Label goes here"));
```

And instead of a `FormLayout` I want to use a `VerticalLayout` but have the same style of Labels for the fields.

```
VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
Label label = new Label("Label goes here");
verticalLayout.add(label);
// setLabelStyleSameAsLabelForTextFieldInFormLayout();
```

In other words what code would replace the method `setLabelStyleSameAsLabelForTextFieldInFormLayout()`?

**Important ->** I'm trying to do it in such a way that doesn't involve creating CSS so that it's more future proof. That is to say if the Label in the `FormLayout` is updated then so is the label in the `VerticalLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

> but have the same style of Labels for the fields.

I have difficulties to understand the question. But this should be trivial by using `setLabel` or label set by constructor of the `TextField`.. So the following should produce the label which looks the same.

```
FormLayout formLayout = new FormLayout();
formLayout.add(new TextField("Label goes here"));

VerticalLayout verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
verticalLayout.add(new TextField("Label goes here"));
```

Comment: It's mainly because I'm using a component that doesn't have a setLabel() method available. For example if you want to add a grid across the bottom of the form but want the grid to have a label then you either need to verticalLayout.add(formLayout, grid) or do formlayout.add(...) and then formLayout.addFormItem(grid) with a colspan of the form. In either case the grid doesn't have a label feature which I'd like to have match the same style as the form. Another example is adding a component wrapped in a VerticalLayout such as a small mini-form or something along those lines (continued)

Comment: By mini form it could be say an image with a radio button group under (or even just display data if it's for a readonly component), in other words some kind of composite component. Instead of creating a custom component sometimes it's just easier to wrap them in a Vertical/Horizontal layout and add that.

Comment: Then one option is to wrap it in CustomField, as it has a label with similar styles.

Comment: For now what I've been doing is adding it to the FormLayout through addFormItem(verticalLayout, " ") so that it has an empty label. It's not ideal solution by any means hence why I'm asking. Don't get me wrong it works but I was looking for a more consistent option without having to create custom components (keeping it lighter weight). Looks like a CustomField is the only option outside of my little hack/workaround. Thanks for the confirmation.